# Azure AD Single Sign In - invalid_grant 9002313 when requesting token with code

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have an existing solution with ASP .NET Core and Angular frontend, with our own user management. Now I want to implement registration and login with Azure Active Directory.

I've successfully set up the AD application and the frontend logic to acquire the code. 
Then I pass it to our backend, to generate a token together with the secret. 
When calling the /oauth2/token endpoint, I get this error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 0a741bc7-c4a7-4699-af50-4e95a5690b00\r\nCorrelation ID: b83b609c-7cdc-4ad6-ae88-6aa07b4243f8\r\nTimestamp: 2020-05-22 19:22:24Z",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-05-22 19:22:24Z",
    "trace_id": "0a741bc7-c4a7-4699-af50-4e95a5690b00",
    "correlation_id": "b83b609c-7cdc-4ad6-ae88-6aa07b4243f8",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
```

I could reproduce the problem with Postman. I tried the tenantid (Guid) as well as the name xxx.onmicrosoft.com

[image]

This is the configuration in Azure AD:
[image]

Comment: You should be using POST for redeeming the code. And you need not include tenant in the form data.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code for samples.

Comment: thank you @maweeras but that didn't solve it. I tried GET and POST before, and I'm studying this same document since days, in case I missed something. 
Using POST, and without tenant and resource (which is optional), it still gives me the same error. Can it have something to do with the application config on the Azure Directory side?

Comment: Most OAuth Flow require https as the redirect URI.  The provided screen shot is not leveraging the secure channel.  Can you try with a redirect using Https?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You follow my process to try to get the `code`:

First register the application,Go to azure portal:
[image]
[image]

Then enter this link in the browser to get the code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={your-client-id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4500/web/completeoauth/ms
&response_mode=query
&state=12345
```

[image]
[image]

Finally use postman to get the access token(Configure as per my request):
[image]

Hope can help you!

Comment: thanks, but I didn't really understand you. I don't see any difference between your POST configuration and mine. but I don't know how to create the flow using jwt.ms ... I'm using a HTTP localhost redirect...

Comment: @StefanR.s   You may have misunderstood what I meant. There is no problem with your configuration. It doesn't matter what kind of redirect you use. I can also get an access token by using your redirect address. I mean you may have copied the extra content when using "code".

Comment: @StefanR.  Because "code" has an expiration time, you need to obtain a new "code". Be careful not to intercept excess content when using "code".

Comment: I was very careful using the extracted code from the callback URL, without any extra content. Also, for every test I use a new code (generating with my preliminary UI), even if the POST for getting a token ended in BadRequest.
Anyway, I expect that the error would be a bit more specific if it's just about an invalid code. I'm afraid there's a small detail missing that I don't see, or that there's still an issue with the AD Application config. 
Perhaps I should create another sandbox, to compare...

Comment: I really appreciate the effort. I did everything again from scratch, carefully following your steps. But still with the same error. I'm not using https locally, but if that were a problem, it shouldn't give me a code in the first place...

Comment: our domain is not verified yet, it's on my todo list. but is that relevant for tests to work? (now it's just a warning to the user who is logging in, I guess that's the only consequence)

Comment: Finally I could solve this issue. @carl Zhao your solution was perfect. I just had a problem with my internal URL management, where we converted the callback to lowercase - which made the code invalid. thanks for all the help anyways!!